# Rename and add prefix to all tables with phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I want to add a prefix and rename all tables in a database with PhpMyAdmin.

I’ve tried these 2 scripts :

1)

```
select concat('rename table', table_name, ' to ', 'prefix_',table_name,';') from information_schema.tables where table_schema='db_name';
```

2)

```
SELECT Concat('ALTER TABLE ', TABLE_NAME, ' RENAME TO osc_', TABLE_NAME, ';') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_schema='db_name';
```

phpMyAdmin says the script is ok (see screen shot) but nothing change. What i am missing with phpMyAdmin ?

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Finally, i found an easy way to do that :

1. select all tables you want to add a prefix
2. choose in the select option : replace prefix table
3. fill the field with the prefix (including the underscore) as in pfx_

Screenshot of phpMyAdmin :

[image: phpMyAdmin select all tables and add table prefix]

[image: phpMyAdmin add table prefix]

[image: result : prefix is added to all tables selected]

Note : In case your website is no more connected to your data base after this modification, you can restart your serveur, MAMP, etc

Comment: thanx ..really helpful