# Rename part of all table names in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently looking for a way, to rename all tables in my db. But I don't want to rename to whole table name (you can find a lot of question about renaming whole table names on SO). So in my case I've a prefix calles `wp_` before each table name what I'll replace with `tnd_`.

So is there a smart way how I can do this? Because I've about 200+ tables and I don't want to change every table name by hand.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using. You have enough rep to know this.

Comment: @JohnConde This was mentioned so I though it's cool to add it. Thanks for removing it!

Comment: No foreign keys, triggers or events on these tables?

Answer (score 1):

I think it would work:

```
SELECT Concat('ALTER TABLE `', TABLE_NAME, '` RENAME TO `dr_', TABLE_NAME, '`;') 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '<name of your db>';
```

Reference: [How to add prefix of all tables in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970798/how-to-add-prefix-of-all-tables-in-mysql)

If you use PHP admin, you can also check: [Rename and add prefix to all tables with phpMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30532620/rename-and-add-prefix-to-all-tables-with-phpmyadmin/30911784)